# Molecular vibrational modes seem to involve most atoms of the molecule, so why IR spectroscopy assign absorptions to particular localized bonds?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy

Spectroscopy texts typically take a molecule, lets's say, an organic molecule with 7 carbons, and assign an absorption of some IR frequency to each particular bond. They attribute, for example, the absorption of higher energy photons to a C-H bond, and a lower energy absorption to a triple bond, and another energy to a C-O bond, and so on.

I questioned myself: -maybe these molecules (like one with 9 carbons), being larger than the typical small molecules in which I am familiar with it's vibrations (CO2 or water), have more localized vibrations.

But after seing simulations on the internet, I realized that the polyatomic molecules also have vibrational modes which tend to involve almost all of its atoms, similar to small molecules. Some vibrational modes giving more amplitude to some atoms than others, but most atoms still vibrate.

So I would expect that, in IR spectroscopy, a particular photon with a particular frequency (energy) would promote a transition between different vibrational levels, making almost the whole molecule vibrate, instead of excite a vibration on a particular localized bond.

Comment: When a C-H bond vibrates, most of the movement is in the hydrogen. But yes, in reality these absorption frequencies involve normal modes of the whole molecule.

Answer (score 0):

An IR instrument works by passing InfaRed radiation through a substance.  The IR detector plots absorbance vs wavelength through the IR range.  Certain functional groups, such as C-H and C=O, absorb strongly at a certain wavelength.  This is what makes this method of analysis valuable.

Whether or not other parts of the molecule get involved in the vibration of the functional group is an interesting, but unnecessary complication of the method.  IR absorbance at a given wavelength is diagnostic of the presence of the matching functional group.

Keep in mind as the test is run the wavelength is constantly changing.